# Why do code files containing unicode string constants saved as UTF8 + BOM display correctly but when saved as UTF8 they do not in classic ASP?

Tags: unicode, asp-classic

I have a code file which I will refer to as "myConstants.res.asp" with a bunch of constants in both English and French...

```
<% 
  const myStr1 = "Bienvenue dans ma maison au moment de cette belle journée de repos et de détente"
  const myStr2 = "Welcome to my house at this beautiful day of rest and relaxation"

  ... more constants ...
%>
```

This constant file is included in other ASP code files that have the following structure...

```
<%@ Language="VBSCRIPT" EnableSessionState=False %>
<% 
    Option Explicit 
    Response.CharSet  = "UTF-8"
    Response.CodePage = 65001    
%>

<!-- #include file = "myConstants.res.asp" -->

... additional code ...
```

If I save the `myConstants.res.asp` file as UTF8+BOM Unicode characters are displayed correctly which in my example case is only an issue for the constant `myStr1`.  In reality I have several hundred of these strings.  If I save the `myConstants.res.asp` file as UTF8 (no BOM).  The Unicode characters show up as garbage.

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Could be the file doing the including is encoded differently?